# Can I bulk/schedule download several of my own YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

I know YouTube doesn't allow normal users to direct download video files but I'm talking about my *own* videos. They have explicit functionality for that so I'm not talking about violating YouTube's Terms of Service or requesting some illicit program.

YouTube has a "Download MP4" button when using Video Manager, but it seems to only let me download three videos at a time, based on some weird timer; after the three downloads are over, it doesn't seem to let me download another.

I have a few hundred uploaded videos that aren't on my HDD due to a lost disk (yes, I backup...but I only kept those videos on the backup disk, which died). I would really like to get local copies of those videos, but downloading them three at a time, especially with an unknown waiting period between batches, just doesn't scale.

Is there some way I can make this easier?

I'm not seeing any other download options on YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org/) provides [Google Takeout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Takeout), which allows Google users to export their data to a downloadable ZIP file. Here is the link to export one's Youtube videos: https://www.google.com/settings/takeout/custom/youtube . It will create an archive containing all the original uploaded videos.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is no option on YouTube for a bulk download. [Documentation is here](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/youtube-1), and is based on Google Takout, which lets you access and remove any info you've stored in Google properties.

On that page there is a link to the [Google Moderator request](https://www.google.com/moderator/#9/e=1d33&g=youtube) for the functionality of a bulk download, feel free to vote the idea up.

Lastly, the official download limit is [2 videos per hour](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56100) when downloading to MP4.

Comment: Just noticed the new limit as I tried to download. At least they clarified how many you get per time period now...

Answer (score 0):

try keepvid.com or jDownloader to download videos from youtube

Comment: These go against Youtube's TOS and the OP said he didn't want to violate their TOS.